# solving a linear equation with one variable in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I am really new to sympy and I have a very simple question.
How can i solve this equation with sympy:

`x + 3 = 5`

I searched the internet but I didn`t find a quick answer to this

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to translate the equation to "something equals zero" form. `x + 3 = 5` thus translates to `x + 3 - 5 = 0`. Then you can feed the "something" part to `sympy.solve`:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
x = Symbol('x')
solve(x + 3 - 5, x)
```

Though you probably did not need a computer to solve that one.